# xcode - Custom fonts on xcode do not appear on xib

Tags: xcode, fonts

I am trying to add new fonts on xcode5 to use them directly on xib file.

My fonts are 3 files. Kelson Sans Bold.otf  Kelson Sans Light.otf and Kelson Sans Regular.otf).

I have:
  -added files to my project
  -edited my .plist adding a "Fonts provided by application" dictionary with 3 items with the complete name (with extention) of fonts files. 
  - added the files into /Library/fonts local directory

But in the interface new fonts do not appear.
I have missed something?

Tx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Fonts added to XCode5 does not work in Interface Builder. You have to set the font by code.

Something like:

```
textField.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Signika-Regular" size:size];
```

or using `NSAttributedString`